# Is there a standard, or widely accepted icon or glyph for 'copy to clipboard'?

Tags: icons

A commonly used interact is clicking a button to copy a long or hard to select string to the clipboard.

Github uses a small clipboard and an entering arrow on the right.

[image]

Gumroad uses a document and plus on the left.

[image]

Before I just design my own, I thought I would ask if there is a standard or widely accepted icon?

Comment: One rule in UX (as far as there can be rules in design, of course) is that you should never use an icon without a label, because there will always be some users that don't know what it means.

Comment: When you copy, where does it go if not the clipboard?

Comment: @NathanRabe good question! I don't know. I have always seen copy to clipboard as opposed to just copy. I wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

Arrow pointing into a clipboard is quite common.

I've also seen a "double clipboard" icon. Two icons stacked on top of each other.

I have also seen a button with the action of "COPY" on it.

I think an important factor is that any similar action follow the same sort of design. Also perhaps a popover.